# What are all the obtainable radio calls in Breakdown?

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown, state-of-decay-yose

I have been trying to find a list of the possible radio calls that can be used in Breakdown (YOSE) and how to get them/which hero they are linked too.

I have found some of the original ones, but they are mostly out of date and do not include the YOSE extras.

So far I have.

#### Basics

- Call For Scavengers
- Establish Outpost
- Settle Home Base
- Words of Encouragement

#### Extra's / Monthly Achievements

- Preppers Pack
- Valentines Gun **(February)**
- Movie Swords (can't remember the name) **(October)**

#### Hero unlocks

- Words of Inspiration (Radio ability that restores max Stamina) (**Pastor William**)
- Vehicle Delivery (**Raymundo Santos**)
- Artillery Support ("Death From Above" radio ability) (**Erik Tan**, **Diane Montressor**, **Royell Vincent**)
- Sniper Support (Adds the Sharpshooting radio ability) (**Mickey Wilkerson**)
- SWAT Support (Adds SWAT Backup radio ability) (**Dan Hovenden**)
- Drone Recon ("Make a lot of noise and kill yourself" radio ability)(**Alicia Hawkes**) *(this is suicidally worthless)*
- Drone Strike (**Kelly Eldridge**)

Comment: The hero characters you will unlock during the game, you can see your progress in the "tab" bar.

Comment: Thats not my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basics

- Call For Scavengers
- Establish Outpost
- Settle Home Base
- Words of Encouragement **(Lily)**

#### Extra's / Monthly Achievements

- Preppers Pack
- Improvised weapon **(Januari)**
- Valentine's Weapon **(February)**
- Gym Weapons **(March)**
- Tow Truck **(April)**
- Collectible Blades **(October)**
- Holiday Pie **(November)**
- Suppressed Weapon **(December)**

#### Hero unlocks

- Words of Inspiration (Radio ability that restores max Stamina) (**Pastor William**)
- Vehicle Delivery (**Raymundo Santos**)
- Artillery Support ("Death From Above" radio ability) (**Erik Tan**, **Diane Montressor**)
- Artillery Support (Costs 20 influence less than the previous and has a separate cooldown counter and item stack) (**Royell Vincent**)
- Sniper Support (Adds the Sharpshooting radio ability) (**Mickey Wilkerson**)
- SWAT Support (Adds SWAT Backup radio ability) (**Dan Hovenden**)
- Drone Recon ("Make a lot of noise and kill yourself" radio ability)(**Alicia Hawkes**) *(this is suicidally worthless)*
- Drone Strike (**Kelly Eldridge**)
- Medical Advice (Heal to full and remove any injury)**(Doc Hanson)**
- Incendiary Barrage **(Kilohana Young)**

Comment: I figured I should just make a Wiki answer in case some people just know 1 or 2 to add to the list. Seeing as SoD2 is only a few months away, I doubt this will get the necessary attention anymore.

Comment: There's also the radio command to unlock Gurbani hero for players who own both SoD and SoD: YOSE